# Обратиться к своему методу в RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, recyclerview

Имеется фрагмент, в котором идёт запрос в базу, затем данные передаются в RecyclerView для формирования списка. По клику на пункт списка открывается активность, там кнопка удаления. По тапу на кнопку идёт запрос в базу на удаление и активность закрывается через финиш.

В методе `onResume()` отлавливается пункт списка, который был удалён и через `mAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(deleteItem);` идёт анимированое скрытие этого пункта из списка.

Всё отлично, но в нижней части экрана появляется дубликат последнего видимого пункта списка. Поискав наткнулся на несколько примеров одного и того же решения - добавление в адаптер своего метода для обновления списка и обращения к этому методу. Один из этих примеров описан в [этом](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/553743?answertab=oldest#tab-top) ответе от [pavlofff](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/177345/pavlofff)

Но почему-то у меня при обращении к методу адаптера в `onResume()` или `onCreateView()` само название метода подсвечивается красным (как будто метод отсутствует), а в самом адаптере название метода подсвечивается серым (как будто метод не используется) и естественно ничего не работает.

[image: screen]

Comment: Скорее всего тип переменной адаптера неверен. Покажите объявление оного и имя класса адаптера

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, не знаю правильно ли будет дублировать информацию из одного вопроса в другой. На всякий случай не буду рисковать. Код фрагмента и адаптера я разместил в [предыдущем вопросе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/725843/) по схожей проблеме. Только сейчас этот код дополнен `onResume` и самими методом в адаптере. Посмотрите, пожалуйста.

Comment: В том вопросе нет указания типа объявленной переменной

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, прошу прощения. В терминах не силён. Что именно и куда нужно прописать?

Comment: У вас есть переменная в фрагменте с именем `myAdapter`. Если вы у неё не можете вызвать метод, описанный в адаптере, то, видимо, тип её определён не как `RecyclerAdapterTab1`, а что-то типа `RecyclerView.Adapter`. Т.е. `RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter`. Если так, то надо лишь заменить тип переменной на тип вашего адаптера, т.е. на `RecyclerAdapterTab1`. Ну или скастовать к нему при вызове метода.

Comment: А удалённый из базы элемент из списка `mDataset` вы удаляете? `mDataset.remove(deletedItem);` Перед тем как сделать `mAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(deleteItem);`.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, спасибо вам большое!! Действительно всё именно так, заменил как подсказали. Добавил `mAdapter.setHasStableIds(true);` во фрагменте и `public long getItemId(int position)` в адаптере. Теперь и информация в писке актуальна, и удаление пункта происходит с анимацией. Спасибо ещё раз, в который раз выручаете ))

Comment: @eugeneek, я делаю заново запрос в базу данных и в методе `mAdapter.dataChanged(myData);` отправляю их адаптеру. Там уже идёт обновление. Или это неверное решение?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В данном случае метод класса `RecyclerAdapterTab1` не виден компилятору, т.к. переменная объявлена с типом `RecyclerView.Adapter`, а у него такого метода нет.

Значит надо или сменить тип переменной

```
//RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter;
RecyclerAdapterTab1 mAdapter;
```

или скастовать к нему при вызове метода

```
RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter;

...

((RecyclerAdapterTab1)mAdapter).dataChanged(data);
```